# Translating linear SVM classification algorithm to C using MATLAB Coder

Tags: algorithm, matlab, classification, svm, matlab-coder

I've trained a linear SVM classifier using the Classification Learner app, and exported the model to a .mat file. I'm attempting to translate this algorithm to C using MATLAB Coder, but am getting an error.

I'm not sure if I'm approaching the problem correctly, but my current approach is to load the .mat file as I would do in MATLAB, and then call the classification prediction function using values that are passed in (this assumes that using `load()` would normally work in MATLAB Coder, of which I'm not sure). When running the "Check for issues" step in MATLAB Coder, the following error is triggered:

> Found unsupported class for variable using function 'load'. MATLAB
>   class 'ClassificationSVM' found at
>   'classifier.trainedClassifier.ClassificationSVM' is unsupported.
>
> Use the command 'whos -file classifierOptimal.mat' to view the
>   variables in the MAT file.

It would appear that the MATLAB class used for classification is unsupported in MATLAB Coder.

How do I translate this classification algorithm for use outside of MATLAB?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears that code generation for SVM routines is not supported:

[MATLAB Answers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/277349-translating-linear-svm-classification-algorithm-to-c-using-matlab-coder)

[MATLAB Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--categorical-list.html#btwz3ma)

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here. It seems to me that you're trying to generate an executable with:

- Loading an external mat file
- External library that needs to be compiled in to your executable

I would read this article about finding mat files for the first issue: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/11/path-management-in-deployed-applications/

I would carefully try to avoid dynamic (i.e. loaded at run time language constructs) while I grasp how the compiler works. Loading an instance from a MAT file asking for trouble.

You're trying to do too many things at the same time, simplify your approach and see what happens.

Comment: Loading the .mat file seems to work; the issue is that the types defined in the .mat file aren't supported by Coder. Do you have any suggestions on a method that doesn't rely on using the .mat file?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing where: classifierOptimal.mat came from, who created it, and who wrote predictFcn, and can it be changed into a standard Matlab function or a mex file?

Comment: The .mat file was generated using the Classification Learner app.